# Get list of open windows form instance that are excuted from different assembly

Tags: c#, window, instance

I have a 'loader app' that loads a menu and when user clicks the menu image button a list view opens based on the text

```
(if text = employee)  
(Go to class A) 
(Go to class B) 
    ...
    ...
    (Show List View Window)
```

if he clicks again on the same button it opens again, I would like to prevent this.
i.e but this for a WPF application

Answer (score 11):

If you want a list of the open forms, that is `Application.OpenForms`. You could iterate over this, using GetType() and checking the `.Assembly` to find those from a different assembly. Beyond that, I'm not entire clear on the question...

```
        Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        List<Form> formsFromOtherAssemblies = new List<Form>();
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms) {
            if (form.GetType().Assembly != currentAssembly) {
                formsFromOtherAssemblies.Add(form);
            }
        }
```

If you just want to track forms you have opened yourself, then cache that instance. Or if you use "owned forms", you can just check by name:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        foreach (Form form in OwnedForms) {
            if (form.Name == "Whatever") {
                form.Activate();
                return;
            }
        }
        Form child = new Form();
        child.Name = "Whatever";
        child.Owner = this;
        child.Show(this);
    }
```

Comment: First,thank you for your reply.

With reference to your first code snippet.
The issue is Application.OpenForms (does not have the forms that
are displayed,it is just a loader) and well 
Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
looks promising... code should be in reverse..mmmm

Comment: Application.OpenForms will return 0 i.e since it is loader

Comment: I'm not sure why your main form just being a loader should affect the outcome here... if the runtime knows about the form, it should appear in Application.OpenForms - unless you mean it is running in a different *process* - is that it?

Comment: the loader is not a main form its a exe that displays a UI (menu) and has no idea what it is displaying. so I need to get the executing assembly but then what? There is some abstraction involved in the code...is it possible to find open forms any other way ?

Answer (score 2):

```
    NewProduct newproduct;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(!isOpened())
        {
            newproduct = new NewProduct();
            newproduct.Show();
        }

    }
    private bool isOpened()
    {
        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (f == newproduct)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please create a WPF Application, and try this.I just tried it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple example

```
private Boolean FindForm(String formName)
    {
        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (f.Name.Equals(formName))
            {

                f.Location = new Point(POINT.X, POINT.Y + 22);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Command pattern. The loader assembly will search for commands in loaded assemblies.
For every command the loader create menu item ( or anything else, you want ), and click event will run the concrete command.

The command must know if should be created new form or used some already existing.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Garvell's answer helped me to figure out what I should do, but it needed adjusting for WPF.

(In my case I wanted to close any windows not owned by the main one when it closes, but the principle is the same.)

```
private void EmployeeMenuItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach(Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if(w.GetType() == typeof(EmployeeListViewWindow)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found)
    {
        EmployeeListViewWindow ew = new EmployeeListViewWindow();
        ew.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could what be adjusted? The new/current window? Yes, just set its properties.

Comment: Oh, right. This is what I did for WPF. I don't think the WPF application has the `OpenForms` property, so I switched to `Application.Current.Windows`