# Calling NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip() from another class

Tags: c#, notifyicon

I'm developing a Windows Form application in C#. I have a main form called MainWindow and a NotifyIcon object called notifyIcon that belongs to the MainWindow class.

What is the best way for me to use notifyIcon from other classes?

I know that, without an instance, I can only access public static members of the class, but if I set the notifyIcon as public static, it stops working on MainWindow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the same application you can use

```
Application.OpenForms
```

to retrieve opened forms.

This property returns a `FormCollection`, you can get the form instance from there. [More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx).

If it's not the same assembly [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388859/c-get-list-of-open-windows-form-instance-that-are-excuted-from-different-assemb).

Comment: I tried this, but when I do 'Form main = Application.OpenForms["MainWindow"];', I'm still unable to call a public method of MainWindow.

Comment: @Jr. You are missing a cast. It's not `Form main`, it should be `var main = Application.OpenForms["MainWindow"] as YourFormThatInheritsFromForm;`. `Form` doesn't know your method, only the child class knows it.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a public method on the form. This method can internally call the methods on notifyicon

Comment: I think for accessing a public method, you need to create a object of that form, and if you create a new object of that form, then there will be 2 notify icons.