# Get Application first run Form

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I have two Forms in a project.
When my application runs, `Form1` is opened. After that I am opening `Form2`.

How can I access `Form1` from `Form2` with reflection?

Comment: Use @JonSkeet method. Otherwise with reflection here is how you do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/388872/495455. As @MarcGravell explains: "If you want a list of the open forms, that is `Application.OpenForms`. You could iterate over this, using GetType() and checking the .Assembly to find those from a different assembly. Beyond that, I'm not entire clear on the question...". Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you want to use reflection for this?

When you create the second form, just pass in a reference to the first one:

```
// I assume it's code within Form1 which opens Form2
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.Show();
```

That's assuming you're happy to add a constructor with `Form2` as a parameter. Alternatively, make it a property in `Form2`:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2 { Form1 = this };
form2.Show();
```

Comment: Is there another way to make it with reflection

Comment: @JuniorSK: Can you explain why you're intent on using reflection?  It's entirely unnecessary in this case.

Comment: I create a component.I have to access component containerform after that I have to access project first runn form for find one of its components

Comment: @JuniorSK: Well that doesn't really give us any more useful information, to be honest. It doesn't make a case for using reflection, certainly.

Answer (score 0):

if you open just one instance of form2 you can do this too:  `Form2 f2 = Application.OpenForms["Form2"];`