# How to switch between Instances(Forms) without creating new ones?

Tags: c#, winforms, instance

I know how to switch form to form, but my problem is that when switching from `Form B` to `Form A`. It always create a new Instance of `Form A`.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388859/get-list-of-open-windows-form-instance-that-are-excuted-from-different-assembly

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: You have to hold a reference to the original form object. Any introductory C# book should explain this.

Comment: you can make your main form as a parent and other form as a child .should you close the main form when switch ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369893/how-to-switch-between-forms-without-creating-new-instance-of-forms

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is called [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

For a very basic approach you can take this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Form1 Instance { get; set; } //Create an Instance Object of your Window

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Your call to open the Window
    private void OpenForm2()
    {
        if (Form2.Instance == null)//Check if Form2 has already been created
        {
            //if not: go create a new one !
            Form2.Instance = new Form2();
        }
        //Instance of Form2 is already created => open that one            
        Form2.Instance.Show();            
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public static Form2 Instance { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```